# How to join strings in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I have three strings:

$str1 = "abc";
$str2 = "def";
$str3 = "ghi";

I can get the value of all of them like this:

echo "$str1$str2$str3";

But I heard there is a way to join them together, so I can echo all of them without quotes.

Comment: Reading documentation seems to become increasingly difficult.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for string concantation.

It's

```
echo $str1 . $str2 . $str3;
```

See https://www.php.net/language.operators.string for more information.

Answer (score 8):

As well as concatenating like this

```
echo $str1 . $str2 . $str3;
```

You can also just output them in sequence, which avoids evaluating an intermediate string

```
echo $str1 , $str2 , $str3;
```

Finally, you can use braces in string to disambiguate string replacement:

```
echo "{$str1}{$str2}{$str3}";
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
echo $str1 . $str2 . $str3;
```